# Mui Autocomplete not firing onChange when losing focus

Tags: javascript, material-ui, autocomplete

Using a Mui `Autocomplete` with `multiple` and `freeSolo`, pressing Return causes an `onChange` event to be fired. However, tabbing out of the Autocomplete widget does not, leaving the text the user has typed still there without the state of the Autocomplete itself having been updated (only the state of the `TextField` within the Autocomplete).

```
  // Called when return is pressed
  function onAddNewItem(e, items) {
    console.log("Validation code goes here");
    setItems(items);
  }

  // Called on a keystroke for the text currently being typed
  function onInputChange(e, newItem) {
    setInputValue(newItem);
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      freeSolo
      disableClearable
      options={[]}
      value={items}
      onChange={onAddNewItem}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      onInputChange={onInputChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} error={error} placeholder="Type here" />
      )}
    />
  );
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-not-firing-onchange-when-losing-focus-528t7f)

How can I cause an `onChange` to be fired, or otherwise set the Autocomplete state on losing focus? Using `onBlur` doesn't help because I'm not passed the 'draft' items from the updated Autocomplete, so cannot set the new Autocomplete state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`autoSelect`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-autoSelect) in autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete
  ....
  autoSelect={true}
/>
```

Comment: Awesome - that did the trick, thank you!